# FusionTables deprecating numeric table ids

Tags: google-fusion-tables

I am pretty confused by the deprecation of the numeric table ids and the introduction of encrypted table ids. I was hoping someone else could shed some light on the significance of this move.

Why would just the "SHOW TABLES", "CREATE TABLE" and "CREATE VIEW" support or return the encrypted table ids. Why don't the other queries like "SELECT" or "INSERT" use the encrypted table ids? What is the reasoning behind this?

So, is the "encid=true" another querystring param that needs to be added to the url alongside the sql or does the sql parameter value itself contain "SHOW TABLES encid=true"? This is not very clear in the docs and the latter option didn't work for me.

Would the "encid=false" option work after the deprecation to return the table's numeric id?

If I use the "encid=true" option to get the encrypted id in my app, how would i go about getting the numeric table id thru code (not manually)? Since I still do need the numeric table ids for the "SELECT", "INSERT", "UPDATE", "DELETE" queries?

Thank You,
Vish

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The encid parameter determines how table ids are *returned*. SHOW TABLES, CREATE TABLE, and CREATE VIEW are the only queries that return table ids in the response, and, hence, the only queries that are affected by the parameter.

Both numeric and encrypted table ids are *accepted* by the SQL API, no parameter required. So, if you're running a SELECT query, you can use the encrypted table id rather than the numeric table id. Here's an example request:

```
https://www.google.com/fusiontables/api/query?sql=SELECT+*+FROM+15UY2pgiz8sRkq37p2TaJd64U7M_2HDVqHT3Quw
```

The encid is a parameter that needs to be added to the URL in addition to the sql parameter. An example request is:

```
https://www.google.com/fusiontables/api/query?sql=SHOW+TABLES&encid=true
```

Eventually numeric table ids will be deprecated. The encid parameter is offered to give developers a chance to test and update their code to make sure it is working in time for the deprecation.

Comment: That explains it. Thank you very much.

Comment: Thanks Kathryn, but what about usage via the Maps API?  Will that eventually switch to the encid as well?

Comment: @EricBridger - short answer: yes. To quell any concerns: no existing Fusion Tables Layers using numeric table ids will break. These will continue to work. Only new tables will be required to use the encrypted table id.

Comment: Thanks Kathryn,I just tried using the encid instead of the numeric id in the 'from' attribute when adding the FusionTables layer to google maps and the layer does not show on the map. The layer does show when I use the numeric id though. Am i missing something?

Comment: Encrypted table ids do not yet work in the Fusion Tables Layer.

Comment: Thanks Kathryn,  When can we expect google Maps API to support the encrypted ids? Currently, i need both the encrypted and the numeric ids since google maps api needs the numeric id. I would just rather make a change just once since our app is in production. If not, i will have to switch to encids on the server side now since numeric id supported is going to be dropped and then later switch the client side maps API code to encrypted id when it supported. Is there a way around this right now?

Comment: We do not plan to deprecate numeric table ids in the SQL API until encrypted table ids are accepted in the Fusion Tables Layer. I would wait until then to change your application.